# Sending PDFs on event notifications and reciepts - disabling

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, email, receipts, pdf

Why is it when you go to:
civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1
Admin->System Settings->Misc

And set "Attach PDF copy to receipts" to "no" that PDFs are still being attached to receipts?

This appears to impact both events and contributions.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that there is an additional setting on CiviContribute Component Settings that appears to override the Misc System Settings which only becomes apparent when you turn on tax/invoicing.
(/civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/contribute?reset=1)

"Automatically email invoice when user purchases online"

This is somewhat confusing.

Perhaps we should change the labels and descriptions such that it's more clear what these options mean.

1. Amend the setting on System->Misc page to reference the fact it might be overridden
2. Change the wording of Civicontribute settings so that it references that by "email invoice" it means attach a pdf (and will override what is set in 1).